# Do I need to install Dell's latest Bios on the XPS 9300 after my upgrade to 20.04?

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, xps

I just upgraded my XPS 13 9300 to Ubuntu 20.04. It shipped to me with Ubuntu 18. So far everything seems to have gone smoothly. I checked the Dell Support website and I noticed that there is a Bios update. I selected Ubuntu 20.04 in the OS dropdown and it does list this Bios. However, the instructions are Windows only and the fact that it is an exe seems to indicate that this is for WIndows only machines. Or am I misunderstanding something? DO I need this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu ships with `fwupd`, a tool for updating the firmware for many devices. Dell actively works on this project, and your laptop is indeed supported, as can be seen on the [fwupd device list entry](https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devices/com.dell.uefie8292593.firmware) for your device.

Their [documentation](https://fwupd.org/lvfs/docs/users) details how to update your system.

Answer (score 5):

I recently did a firmware upgrade on my HP, here are my notes:

`sudo fwupdmgr get-devices` (will tell you which devices you can update using fwupdmgr)

`sudo fwupdmgr get-updates` (will tell you which devices have an update)

`sudo fwupdmgr update` (this will update the devices that have an available update pending)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

This [documentation](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-in/000131486/update-the-dell-bios-in-a-linux-or-ubuntu-environment) will give you enough information you need. You can't use EXE as it's only for Windows. BIOS updates are not specific to an operating system. It's for the hardware but to make it easy for the users, OEMs will create applications (EXEs for Windows) to achieve the BIOS update. Dell's official website will show only Windows executables but you'll find the steps need to achieve the same in Ubuntu in the documentation mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: "You can't use EXE as it's only for Windows" might not be always the case now - my 2020 Dell Inspiron 3793 BIOS was able to update itself using the .EXE from Dell's web site (no Windows, only Kubuntu installed but not involved other than downloading the .EXE to the FAT32 boot partition).